# In R, discover rows which partially match rows in another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, match

I have the following two data frames:

```
> df1
# A tibble: 4 x 4
    x     y     z     w
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    4     5     8     9
    4     6     7     4
    3     6     7    10
    8     2     8     9
> df2
# A tibble: 4 x 4
    x     y     z     w
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    6     2     7     9
    2     6     7    10
    4     5     8    12
    4     5     8     3
```

I would like to discover which rows in df2 have a match in df1, where a match means being identical in at least n/2 columns.

So in this example, row 1 in df2 is a match to row 4 in df1 (columns 1 and 3), row 2 in df2 matches row 2 in df1 on columns 2 and 3 and row 3 on columns 2,3,4 and so on.

I also have to save the location of the repeating rows and the columns on which they match.

For small data sets, I could replicate both data sets and subtract them and count the zeros. However what I need is a solution which would work on very large data sets (~20K rows).

Any ideas? A dplyr solution (rather than a data.table) would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you exactly mean when you have written as _For small data sets, I could replicate both data sets and subtract them and count the zeros_

Comment: I could replicate each dataset 4 times, so that each row in df1 will be compared to each row in df2.

Comment: That's what I had guessed. In what format do you expect result to be?

Comment: df1 will now be a 16x4 data frame, and so will df2. If I now subtract them I will have a 16x4 data frame of zeros and non-zeros, and the location of these zeros will indicate which rows are matching

Comment: Have a look at answer. Now if you are looking for having only those rows that have more than 50% matching columns then we can modify function to do the same and result only those rows meeting criteria.

Comment: Thanks MKR. I tried something very similar to your solution, and it becomes very computationally expensive - it scales as N^2, where N is the number of rows.

Comment: We can optimize solution but I wanted to first confirm the expected output? The result suggest only 2 rows will meet criteria but you have mentioned about 3 rows in your description.

Comment: I think the problem here is that for some reason you are replicating columns rather than rows, so e.g. your first row is 4 4 3 8 rather than 4 5 8 9

Comment: Got the logic. I was missing one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This final output might not be the ideal format, but it should at least have the information you're looking for and work with many more fields/columns.

```
df1 <- read.table(text =
             "x     y     z     w
              4     5     8     9
              4     6     7     4
              3     6     7    10
              8     2     8     9",
              header = T)

df2 <- read.table(text =
             "x     y     z     w
              6     2     7     9
              2     6     7    10
              4     5     8    12
              4     5     8     3",
              header = T)


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

Add a row ID number to each data frame and reshape the data from wide to long with `gather`. (I'm assuming each row can be treated as a unique id):

```
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(df1_id = row_number()) %>%
  gather(field, value, x:w) %>% 
  arrange(df1_id)

df2 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(df2_id = row_number()) %>% 
  gather(field, value, x:w) %>% 
  arrange(df2_id)
```

Join the two data frames with an `inner_join` on field/column and value. Then use `group` and `filter` to get only field and value combinations that have two or more matches

```
df2 %>% 
  inner_join(df1, by = c('value', 'field')) %>%
  group_by(df2_id, df1_id) %>% 
  filter(n()>=2) %>%  # where 2 is the minimum number of matches
  arrange(df2_id, df1_id, value) %>% 
  select(df2_id, df1_id, field, value)

# A tibble: 13 x 4
# Groups:   df2_id, df1_id [5]
   df2_id df1_id field value
    <int>  <int> <chr> <int>
 1      1      4 y         2
 2      1      4 w         9
 3      2      2 y         6
 4      2      2 z         7
 5      2      3 y         6
 6      2      3 z         7
 7      2      3 w        10
 8      3      1 x         4
 9      3      1 y         5
10      3      1 z         8
11      4      1 x         4
12      4      1 y         5
13      4      1 z         8
```

You can see that df2 row id 1 matches df1 row 4 on the fields y and w,
df2 row 2 matches df1 row 2 on fields fields y and z,
df2 row 2 also matches df1 row 3 on fields y, x, and w.
df2 rows 3 and 4 match df1 row 1 on x, y, and z.

`arrange` and `select` are really only necessary for easier viewing of the data.

Comment: Thanks! That's the kind of solution I was looking for! awesome

Answer (score 0):

How bout this? Using `dplyr` and `purrr`, we add `id.1`/`id.2` fields and append `.1` or `.2` to the existing fields to both data frames as appropriate. Then we create a list of vectors for the `by` parameter. We will iterate through each vector when `inner_join`-ing `df2` to `df1`, concatenate all the results from the `inner_join`-ing, and selecting the `id`s from both data frames.

```
require(dplyr)
require(purrr)

df1 <- tibble(
  x = c(4, 4, 3, 8),
  y = c(5, 6, 6, 2),
  z = c(8, 7, 7, 8),
  w = c(9, 4, 10, 9)
)

df2 <- tibble(
  x = c(6, 2, 4, 4),
  y = c(2, 6, 5, 5),
  z = c(7, 7, 8, 8),
  w = c(9, 10, 12, 13)
)

df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(id.1 = 1:length(.)) %>%
  rename(
    x.1 = x,
    y.1 = y,
    z.1 = z,
    w.1 = w
  )

df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(id.2 = 1:length(.)) %>%
  rename(
    x.2 = x,
    y.2 = y,
    z.2 = z,
    w.2 = w
  )

inner_join_by <-
  list(
    c("x.1" = "x.2", "y.1" = "y.2"),
    c("x.1" = "x.2", "z.1" = "z.2"),
    c("x.1" = "x.2", "w.1" = "w.2"),
    c("y.1" = "y.2", "z.1" = "z.2"),
    c("y.1" = "y.2", "w.1" = "w.2"),
    c("z.1" = "z.2", "w.1" = "w.2")
  )

filtered <- inner_join_by %>%
  map_df(.f = ~inner_join(x = df1, y = df2, by = .x)) %>%
  select(id.1, id.2) %>%
  distinct()
```

Comment: I agree - it works well for exactly 2 columns. In a general case I would have n columns (e.g. 20) and the match has to be on at least 10...

Comment: I think if we scale it up to such cases, the problem would be in generating the combinations in the `inner_join_by` variable rapidly. Aside from that, we can just keep looking at the minimum number of fields that must match (in your example, 10), and we'll be able to solve the problem sufficiently.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be using `apply` row-wise:

```
apply(df1, 1, function(x)apply(df2,1,function(y)x==y))

#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
# [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [3,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [4,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [6,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [7,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [8,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [9,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [10,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [11,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [12,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [13,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [14,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [15,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [16,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Actually, apply is not even necessary - this can be done vectorially. However, when each data frame has 20K rows, this might be computationally prohibitive

Comment: We can optimize it. But I just wanted to know is that what you were looking for? I can see only two rows have `TRUE` more than 2. Hence you result would be row 6 and 11.

Comment: @OmryAtia Have a look. As you can notice extraditing to multiple dataframe size is not needed. Obviously iteration will be.

Comment: I am now running this on two data frames with 12K rows and 3 columns. Already taking 5 minutes. Question: How is your solution different from running the function 12,000^2 times?

Comment: Apply or other function doesn't always gives you benefit of performance. They simplify the logic to write and understand. Hence, for-loop can give you a better performance in this case.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following solution (still involving a loop):

Here the function which for a given row checks and returns matches:

```
fct <- function(x, dat){
  M1logical <- t(unlist(x) == t(dat))
  n <- which(rowSums(M1logical) > 1)
  if(length(n) > 0){
    return(n)
  }
  if(length(n) == 0){
    return(0)
  }
}
```

Now applying iterating:

```
mylist <- rep(list(NA), nrow(df2))
for(k in 1:nrow(df2)){
  mylist[[k]] <- fct(df2[k,], df1)
}
```

It takes my computer 23.14 seconds (`microbenchmark`) to compute it with two data frames of size 20000x4 each, see here for the dummy data (roughly 45 seconds on an older device):

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=sample(1:20,20000, replace = T), y=sample(1:20,20000, replace = T), 
              z=sample(1:20,20000, replace = T), w=sample(1:20,20000, replace = T),
              stringsAsFactors = F)
df2 <- data.frame(x=sample(1:20,20000, replace = T), y=sample(1:20,20000, replace = T), 
              z=sample(1:20,20000, replace = T), w=sample(1:20,20000, replace = T),
              stringsAsFactors = F)
```